# MongoDB unexpected token? when using $gte

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm trying to get all documents that are greater than the current date, based on an 'end_date' field.

I'm using this:

```
db.collection.find({end_date: {$gte: new Date()}})
```

But I get a syntax error near  `` `{end_date:' ``

Syntax seems to right  - am I missing something?

Thank you!

Comment: I've just tried this, and it works for me (with MongoDB 2.0.3):
erick@whisky:/tmp$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.3
connecting to: test
> use demo
switched to db demo
> db.collection.find({end_date: {$gte: new Date()}})

Comment: Strange... I just reconnected and it worked. Maybe I had a space or something.. thanks! can you answer this so I can select you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax works just fine for me:

```
derick@whisky:/tmp$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.3 
connecting to: test 
> use demo 
switched to db demo 
> db.collection.find({end_date: {$gte: new Date()}})
>
```